# QGIS MergeShapes Error

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes

I am using the MergeShapes plugin with QGIS 1.8.0 on a Windows 7 computer.  The issue I am having is when I perform a merge from a directory based on one geometry type, and then switch the geometry type to process a second time (ie: process all polygons in c:\Temp and then process lines in the same directory).  This is a limitation when you need to preform multiple merges based on geometry.  Any help would be appreciated.  Below is the error from MergeShapes.

An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ryangarnett/.qgis//python/plugins\mergeshapes\mergeshapesdialog.py", line 141, in accept
    self.progressFiles.setRange( 0, self.inputFiles.count() )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/ryangarnett/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/ryangarnett/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\Users\ryangarnett\.qgis\python\plugins\qgis2kml', 'C:\Users\ryangarnett\.qgis\python\plugins\qgis2kml', '/usr/share/qgis/python', '~/.qgis/python', '.', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools', '~/.qgis/python', '.']

Comment: Have you tried other plugins such as the Merge Shape Layer function in mmqgis or the even respective function in the Qgis vector menu?

Comment: Yes, I have tried them, with the same issue.

Comment: Does it work if you restart the plugin between processing polygons and lines? If this is reproducible, it's probably best to file a bug report.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been doing.  I as hoping there was an alternative.  Maybe a ticket entry for this to be fixed for the next release?